# How to load all data's in a MongoDB Collection using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to load and return all data's in a collection for example all of the users in Users collection ,
i've searched and found `User.find()` or `User.find({})` without any expression or object as input but it throws an error when i program tries to send the result as JSON : `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Route Code :

```
router.get('/getAllUser',auth,async(req,res)=>{ let users= User.find(); console.log(users) return res.status(200).send(users); }
```

Comment: It should be code issue, you need to give your code in order to get an answer for this..

Comment: i've added the code to the main question , it's is a simple GET method and every thing you see in code is defined even when i put an expression in find() method it finds and returns user without any problem , error appears only when i try to return whole users

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Assume that your collection name is "customers":

```
dbo.collection("customers").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
```

Hope this wil be helpfull

Comment: It's normal for you to get an error. I had assumed that dbo represents your instance of connection to MongoDB. Go here to see how to connect to your MonB https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_find.asp